# asp.net call url to get information

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, http

I'm trying to implement a domain search in our website, but I have no clue how... the WHOIS service I registered by, gave me an API key to use... When I use the following address in my browser's url, 
http://api.robowhois.com/v1/availability/example.com

a login box appears, asking me for my username and password, when I type in my username and password which is the key they gave me, a page appears with the following

```
    {
  "response": {
"available": false
  }
}
```

I'm sorry to say, but I've been searching for weeks on how to solve this but at the end my last resort was to turn to stack overflow... can someone please help, is there a way on how to use and call the url and use the info?

Answer (score 1):

You already got the information you need. It responds with a JSON object saying it's not available.

To retrieve the information as you wish, you can use Jquery, just put your URL in a function as in the examples and get `data.response.available` value and assign it to your textbox etc. For more information how to make JSON calls and parse them, check out [this documentation in Jquery website](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/).

Comment: Yes but how do I use my asp:textbox and button to retrieve the information

Answer (score 0):

> RoboWhois is a web service that provides an API suite to access WHOIS
>   records and domain related information with a unified, consistent
>   interface. Using RoboWhois API you can retrieve WHOIS details parsed
>   as convenient JSON structure.

In order to check the availability of a given domain you have to send a http get request to the robowhois api `http://api.robowhois.com/v1/availability/example.com`

The server does answer the request by sending http response containing json which looks like this:

```
{
  "response": {
    "available": false
  }
}
```

which means the domain is no longer available.

In order to use the information contained in the json response you should deserialize the json object to a c# object. You can do this for example with the [json.net library](http://json.codeplex.com/).

Here is a small example from the documentation on how to use json.net to deserialize a json:

```
Product product = new Product();
product.Name = "Apple";
product.ExpiryDate = new DateTime(2008, 12, 28);
product.Price = 3.99M;
product.Sizes = new string[] { "Small", "Medium", "Large" };

string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(product);
//{
//  "Name": "Apple",
//  "ExpiryDate": "2008-12-28T00:00:00",
//  "Price": 3.99,
//  "Sizes": [
//    "Small",
//    "Medium",
//    "Large"
//  ]
//}

Product deserializedProduct = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Product>(output);
```